# The correct use of timers in a thread group (Until now my timers get ignored)

Tags: performance, jmeter, stress-testing

My goal is to simulate 500 users that perform certain requests on the website in an amount of time of five minutes.

To make the test come as as close as possible to reality, I want to add a thinking time between requests (here: two seconds). The problem is no matter what I do, the timers get ignored. To give you an example, I would like to perform an login request every 2 seconds. Here is data of the thread group:

```
Number of Threads: 500
Ramp-Up Period: 300
Loop Count: 1
```

**So what I did do till now to achieve this:**

1. I used the constant timer and put it at as a child to my request, that didnt work, timer gets just ignored, no matter what value I use.
2. I tried the constant throughput timer, but that didnt work too, values get ignored.

What am I doing wrong. I added a screenshot so you are able to see where I did put the constant timer in my test plan.

Screenshots of my testplan:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can work without timers, you can use the Ramp up period to be Number of threads * 2 (seconds) to start Thread every 2 seconds approximately.

So in your case just put Ramp-Up Period: 1000 (and remove timer)

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong timer, Constant Timer just adds delay of 5 seconds before each request. If you want JMeter to perform login each 2 seconds you should consider switching to [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer)

[image: JMeter Constant Throughput Timer]

Remember that Constant Throughput Timer acts precisely enough on **minute** level only so you might need to play with ramp-up period on Thread Group level in order to limit threads execution rate during first 60 seconds. Alternatively you can consider using [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) plugin